# Parse the output of a grep to tag files

Tags: parsing, grep, tags, pipe

After a lengthy pipe which ends with a grep,  I correctly end up with a set of matching absolute paths/files and match string separated by a comma delimiter for each.   I want to tag each file with its match string.   Complicated also in that the path has spaces but there is none between the delimiter and the preceding and succeeding characters.

I need to be able to deal with an absolute path rather than just the filename within the directory.  The match strings are space_free but the filename might not be:

So by way of example, the output of the pipe might look like:

```
pipe1 | pipe2 | 

outputs


/Users/bloggs/Directory One/matched_file.doc,attributes_0001ABC
/Users/bloggs/Directory One/matched_file1.doc,attributeY_2
/Users/bloggs/Directory One/match_file_00x.doc,Attribute_00201
/Users/bloggs/Directory One/matching file 2.doc,attribute_0004
```

I want to tag each using something which will probably include:

```
    tag --add "$attribute" "$file"
```

Where attribute refers to the match string eg "Attribute_00201"

Normally I'd just say eg:

```
   tag --add Attribute_00201  /Users/bloggs/Directory\ One/match_file_00x.doc
```

At this point I am stuck how to parse each line ideally via another pipe and to deal with spaces correctly and execute the tag command.  Grateful for any help

So I'm looking for a new pipe,  pipe3 to execute or give me the correctly formatted tag command:

```
pipe1 | pipe2 | pipe3

delivers eg

tag --add Attribute_00201  /Users/bloggs/Directory\ One/match_file_00x.doc


etc
etc
```

This seems to work

```
| tee  >(cut -f2 -d","| sed  's/^/tag --add  /' > temp_out.txt) >(cut  -d"," -f1 |   sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\\ /g' > temp_out1.txt) > /dev/null && paste -d' ' temp_out.txt  temp_out1.txt   > command.sh && chmod +x ./command.sh
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sample input is in the first code block 'output of the pipe'     Desired output is an additional pipe which delivers the functionality shown in the second and third code blocks shown above.